# Hibernate generates unneeded join clause and fails (migrating from 3.5.6 to 3.6.10)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

We have a problem when trying to migrate hibernate from 3.5.6 to 3.6.10. We are using hbm.xml configuration files. Here is the criteria:

```
public List<Cat> findCats(Com com) {

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Occupe.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("com", com));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("datLibPt"),
            Restrictions.gt("datLibPt", Calendar.getInstance().getTime())));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("delDate"));
    criteria.createAlias("cat", "cat");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.isNull("cat.delDate"));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("cat.csv"));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("cat"));

    return findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

With Hibernate 3.5.6, it generates the following query:

```
Hibernate: select this_.TRA_ID as y0_ from mydb..OCCUPE this_ 
inner join mydb..CAT cat1_ on this_.TRA_ID=cat1_.TRA_ID where this_.COM_ID=? and (this_.OCC_DAT_LIB_FCT is null or this_.OCC_DAT_LIB_FCT>?) and this_.DELDATE is null and cat1_.DELDATE is null order by cat1_.TRA_CSV asc
```

With Hibernate 3.6.10 it generates the following query:

```
select this_.TRA_ID as y0_ from mydb..OCCUPE this_ 
inner join mydb..CAT cat1_ on this_.TRA_ID=cat1_.TRA_ID 
inner join mydb..CAT cat1_ on this_.TRA_ID=cat1_.TRA_ID where this_.COM_ID=? and (this_.OCC_DAT_LIB_FCT is null or this_.OCC_DAT_LIB_FCT>?) and this_.DELDATE is null and cat1_.DELDATE is null order by cat1_.TRA_CSV asc
```

and fails subsequently because of the (logical) error `com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Tables 'mydb..CAT' and 'mydb..CAT' have same exposed names.`

The 3.6.10 query is strictly similar to the 3.5.6 one except for the duplicated inner join statement. I am trying to understand this weird behavior. I think I am going to use a HQL request instead, but if you have any hint, don't hesitate to comment ;)

Comment: After some experimentations, I figured that the problem arise starting from Hibernate 3.6.6. For the moment I will stick to 3.6.5 until I have solved every other problem